# Можно ли в Java изменить значение final переменной с помощью рефлексии?

Tags: java, static, рефлексия, final

```
public class start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        UnderTest test = new UnderTest();

        System.out.println("До рефлекшина : " + test.getA());

        Field field = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("nomber");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(test, 666);
        System.out.println("После рефлецшина : " + test.getA());
    }
}

class UnderTest{

    private final int nomber = 55;
    public int getA() {

        return nomber;
    }
}
```

Вывод :
До рефлекшина : 55
После рефлецшина : 55

Comment: Зачем вам это надо?

Comment: просто интересно, допустим на момент выполнения перебить библиотечные константы

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: Можно, но более деструктивного применения рефлексии придумать сложно, с высокой долей вероятности это приведёт к появлению целой кучи гейзенбагов или даже падению программы.

Comment: Но в консольном выводе видно что значение не изменилось, т.е соответсвенно и само значение осталось прежним.

Comment: смотря как вы инициализируете. Если в правой части - константное выражение, то его результат [будет подставлен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389085) вместо переменной при компиляции в байткод, и рефлексия ничего не даст. Если нет, то установка возможна, но если объект опубликован, то видимость изменения [не гарантирована](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код меняет значение `final` переменной, только поскольку для установки значения вы используете рефлексию, то для вывода значения тоже нужно использовать рефлексию

```
System.out.println("После рефлецшина : " + field.get(test));
```